# Show leading whitespaces, but not including tabs

Tags: search, whitespace, tab-characters

I am a tabs kind of guy, I do not like when my code contains leading whitespaces instead of leading tabs. I often exchange codes with colleagues and I first have to convert the leading whitespaces to tabs manually before doing anything else.

Is there a way to search for whitespaces but not tabs in vim? My end goal is to write a script that will convert leading whitespaces to tabs automatically, but an answer to the above question will put me in the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `/`  will search for single space (there's a space after slash)
- `/^ \+` will search for leading whitespaces

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [@grodzik's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10053/16706) here are two points that might interest you:

You can have vim showing the tabs and spaces characters. If you use:

```
set list
set listchars+=tab:>-,space:.
```

You'll see lines like this (Here the line begins with 2 tab characters and 4 spaces characters):

[image]

See [`:h 'list'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27list%27) and [`:h 'listchars'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27)

---

Also about the transformation of the tabs to spaces the `:retab` command might interest you. From [`:h :retab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aretab):

> With `!`, Vim also replaces strings of only normal
>   spaces with tabs where appropriate.

Thus in a the buffer containing my previous example if I use `:retab!` I'll get:

[image]

You can imagine using the command in an autocommand for example to automatically convert your new buffers.